# LINQ statement is returning "Invalid object name" error

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm completely new to LINQ. I'm just trying to do some easy stuff but I got an error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.grupyTowarowe'.

I could have sworn this worked couple min ago and I didn't change anything.

This is the code:

```
var papier = from GrupyTowarowe in dbContext.grupyTowarowes
             where GrupyTowarowe.typ == "moneta"
             select new
             {
                 GrupyTowarowe.grupa
             };

dataGridView1.DataSource = papier;
```

The error is shown on the DataGridView.

Comment: Something is wrong with the database you are talking to, go check that. This has nothing to do with LINQ and is a problem with your Entity Framework

Comment: Check whether this DB object `'dbo.grupyTowarowe'` does exists in your DB

Comment: Of course it exist, as i said couple mins ago it works perfectly

Comment: "Of course it exist" The error message says otherwise.

Comment: I can't post photo cause i need 10rep points but its exist ^

Comment: Check your connection string. Make sure it points to the database you think it does.

Comment: check your table names

Comment: This is something in your configuration, maybe db privileges. It's not code-related and therefore it's almost impossible for us to give you any useful hint.

Answer (score 0):

Check the schema of 'grupyTowarowe' - it may be different if you've moved to a different database. Eg, your dev database might have it as schema 'dbo' but the next database could create your object under a different schema. If that is the case, use the ALTER SCHEMA command in SSMS.

Answer (score -2):

When you create an anonymous object using "select", you must assign to a field so that it can be referenced.

```
select new
{
   Grupa = GrupyTowarowe.grupa
}
```

However, it really looks like all you want is the result. In that case, you do not create an object you simply select the object that is returned.

```
var papier = from GrupyTowarowe in dbContext.grupyTowarowes
             where GrupyTowarowe.typ == "moneta"
             select GrupyTowarowe;
```

**Correction:**

The original syntax for the anonymous class is legal. I have lived and breathed this stuff for over a decade. I just never tried this syntax. You learn new things every day.

**Update:**

This answer is mostly incorrect, especially since the OP's error is related to the Entity Framework, not Linq. But I am leaving it (feel free to downvote) since there are useful comments that explain why the answer is wrong.

Comment: the error is not because of this @rhaben, the same error will still show even with your solution. And also takitamnick is selecting only one property out of the object.

Comment: In order to use it as a data source, for a grid, you need the results to be wrapped in an object with named properties.  And the OP's anonymous object constructor is syntactically legal.  For expressions named by identifiers, the property name is implied if not specified.

Comment: I have not directly used the entity framework. Sounds like EF magic makes that syntax work. I did wonder about the table error. Thanks!

Comment: @rhaben:  There certainly is  a lot of magic in EF, but you don't even need linq to use that syntax.  For instance, this creates an object with a `Length` property whose value is 3.  `new { "abc".Length }`

Comment: Yes, I was busy in my sandbox trying it with just plain Linq and was astonished when it worked.  I also tried it with multiple fields and it worked as well. I had gotten the impression it would only work with one field. But that is not the case.Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, I also checked as to whether the anonymous class creates Fields or Properties. It is definitely Properties. That is also new info. I kind of always assumed it was a Field. Never had a reason to ask.